# inpython SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal using platform.techsmart.codes trying to play a sound while start is pressed

Tags: python, syntax-error, python-3.4, eol

I was trying to play an intro sound when the start button is pressed but no matter what i did the error kept popping up.

This was my code that was getting an error :

```
def intro():
intro = ['ElectricGuitarA.mp3','ElectricGuitarB.mp3','ElectricGuitarC.mp3']
if button.is_colliding_rect(x,y):'
intro.play[1]
```

I expected it to play either intro 1 or 2 when button is colliding with mouse,
what actually happened was the error.

Comment: Why do you have an apostrophe after one of the colons? (If the answer is "because without it, I got a different error", well, putting the apostrophe in didn't fix that error. It just hid that error with a new error.)

Comment: oh i didnt see that haha thanks i hope that was the error

Comment: now it says TypeError: is_colliding_rect() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Comment: When you have a new question, best make a new one - as it is a totally different problem. Or do a total overhaul of this one - but this is also in general not a good practice as our comments will then not make sense anymore.

Comment: oh ok, thanks I will remember that, in fact, I will make a new question right now but should I delete the question I put in the comments?